# how to flip upside down range to setvalues?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

ive used it before, but cant remember and searching all i find is transpose, which isnt what im looking for

just to invert row order upside down

```
a  1     c  3
b  2  >  b  2
c  3     a  1
```

basic code im using:

```
  var Data = ss_s.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).getValues();
  ss_t.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).setValues(Data);
```

i remember i did something like

```
  ss_t.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).setValues.inverted(Data);
```

but i cant cant find correct funcion

Comment: Perhaps it was reverse() since setValues returns an array

Comment: thanks cooper, indeed it was reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
 ss_t.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).setValues.inverted(Data);
```

use

```
ss_t.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).setValues(Data.reverse());
```

`Range.getValues()` returns an Array of Arrays (Array 2D).

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse